# Possible to use print() function to place images in PDFs?

Tags: r, image, pdf, printing, shiny

I am using the print() function to place lattice graphs into a pdf and it works great.  I want to place images into a pdf using the print() function.  I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is the code, speficically the 4th line:

```
createPdf <- function() {
    temp <- tempfile(fileext=".pdf")
    pdf(file=temp, height=8, width=11)
    print('image.png',position=c(0,0,0.6,0.7),more=TRUE)   #display an image here
    print(returns$bar,position=c(0.6,0.6,1,1), more=TRUE)  #display barchart1   
    print(returns2$bar2,position=c(0.6,0.0,1,0.6))         #display barchart2
    dev.off()
    return(temp)
}
```

The lattice graphs display just fine, the image.png doesn't display at all.  Does anyone have any advice as to what I am doing wrong?  Is there a special file format I must use or something I need to add to the print() function?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try `grid::grid.raster(png::readPNG('image.png'))`

Comment: baptiste, thanks a bunch, that was a big help.  When I put the grid::grid.raster into the print statement, it displays the png on a separate page by itself, as big as possible.  Is there a way to control that output so it is regular size and on the page with the other plots?  Thanks again

Comment: you need to learn a bit about grid viewports for that. try `?grid::viewport`